# exit() call pthread_mutex_lock()

Tags: c, pthreads, libc

I have a strange problem with threads. If I start my program without arguments or with a `--help` option, it will exit immediately.

The program loads a network checker thread on start. When it is time to exit or disable some online functions, it simply terminates the network checker thread. This appears to be done correctly... until I call `exit()`.

On gdb i can see that the network checker is successfully closed - but for some obscure reasons when the main program calls `exit()` then `pthread_mutex_lock()` is also called.

Here's the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff711e804 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff711a0e0 in _L_lock_533 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff7119f79 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff7dea3cd in _dl_fini () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff6dbe6a1 in __run_exit_handlers () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff6dbe725 in exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000000000413ec4 in option_handler (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdcb8) at autocrack.c:302
#7  0x00000000004135a7 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdcb8) at autocrack.c:34
```

This *does not* happen when I call `exit()` from inside my `main` function. This only happens when I call `exit()` [from inside the option handler](https://github.com/tux-mind/autocrack/blob/3cb167b1d0732ce38e50db77d403f3ba4aa22fbf/autocrack.c#L302).

I used `grep -rin pthread_mutex_ .` to see where else locks are used in my program: the program should never reach these points.

The full source code can be found at https://github.com/tux-mind/autocrack

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

The lock is being obtained from `_dl_fini`, an internal function in the dynamic linker/loader responsible for running global destructors in shared library files. It has to obtain a lock to ensure that no new libraries are being loaded (via `dlopen`) at the same time it's running destructors.

If you're experiencing a crash or hang at this point, you've invoked undefined behavior somewhere in your program, probably via writes through invalid pointers. Valgrind may be able to help you determine where the bug in your program is.

Comment: +1: I'd say it is likely that the memory corruption happened on top of the library's pthread_mutex memory. It probably believes the mutex is locked and is waiting for it to be unlocked, which will of course never happen.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, 
valgrind ins't useful because it stops with the deadlock.
if i press Ctrl+C my program catch this and suicide...but valgrind still frozen.
the very strange things is that when my program isn't already dead ( waiting on SIGINT ) i cannot se it in ps --ppid `pidof valgrind` -L, why?

Comment: in config.log i find this option which is given to configure:
--enable-__cxa_atexit
but it should work only in c++, right?

Comment: Which program's config.log? That sounds like it's just the output of `gcc -v` telling you *how gcc was configured*, not anything to do with your program...

Comment: is the log of the ./configure script....here you are: http://pastebin.com/Awqn0xhR

Comment: Yes, that's just showing the options your version of gcc was compiled with.

Comment: can i provide more data for find out the bug?
forget me if i reply quite late but i'm under exams.....